# When I change array to vector, the program is abnormal

Tags: c++, for-loop, g++, nested-loops, stdvector

When I use an `array`, the following code works well. I tried to replace `array` with `std::vector`, but found that procedures often appear abnormalities, need to run more times. Anything I missed? I am using g++ 10.3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    for (int k = 1; k <= 4; ++k) {
//        int *A = new int[k]();
        std::vector<int> A(k, 0);
        int i = 0;
        for (; i >= 0; A[i]++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
                std::cout << A[j] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
            for (i = k - 1; i >= 0 && A[i] == n - 1; i--)
                A[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My bet is on an out-of-bounds access. With the std::vector version, try replacing accesses like A[i] with A.at(i), which will perform bounds checking, which may highlight where the problem occurs.

Comment: @expression What is this silly code doing? The variable i is used in two nested loops.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I was exactly thinking the same:) Somehow i becomes -1 somwhere. So I would also say that std::vector doesn't cause abnormalities but shows that there are other abnormalities.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow compute the cartesian product of n numbers, like Python's `itertools.product(range(n), repeat=k)`

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use a `vector<int>` or `new int[]`. Your code accesses the array out of bounds in `for (i = k - 1; i >= 0 && A[i] == n - 1; i--) A[i] = 0;`. Compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` to get help with runtime problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this for loop in its  third part

```
for (; i >= 0; A[i]++) {
               ^^^^^^
```

the variable `i` can be equal to `-1` after the inner loop

```
for (i = k - 1; i >= 0 && A[i] == n - 1; i--)
```

where the same variable `i` is used (for example when `k` is equal to `1`).

So it is unimportant whether you are using a vector or an array. The program has undefined behavior.